# Why is "System.Byte[]" coming when "byte[]" is entered?

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner to programming and use C# to learn programming. When I enter this code

`byte[] bytes={1,2,3};
 Console.WriteLine(bytes);`

the output is`System.Byte[]`.
Why is that? How can I fix it?

Comment: That's because arrays do not override the default `ToString` implementation which is to just print the name of the type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Common method for printing arrays and lists of any types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655262/common-method-for-printing-arrays-and-lists-of-any-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

*iteration* - the repetition of a process or utterance.

Answer (score 3):

Console.WriteLine generally expects a string. If the value or object passed in as parameter is of a different type, it will convert the value or object internally to a string by calling its .ToString() method. The .ToString method of any array type will only return the type name, not its content. You presumably want to print out the content of the array. @Aquaballin's answer is almost what you tried to accomplish, except for the superfluous line breaks. I'll also add some commas as delimiters.

```
foreach (byte b in bytes)
{
    Console.Write(b);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

As per the removed comment on your post, you need to iterate over each byte to get the value. As it is, you're simply printing out the type when you try and print an array and not it's elements.

```
byte[] bytes = { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach(byte b in bytes)
{
    Console.Write(b);
}
```

I think that @Aquaballin beat me to the punch; we even use a similar method of iterating! :D

Answer (score 2):

The console is writing out the string value of the byte array, which is "System.Byte[]".

You need to print out each item in the Byte array individually, which is most simply done like this:

```
foreach(Byte item in bytes)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Console.WriteLine(obj)` implicitly calls the ToString method on the passed parameter. In the case of a System.Byte[] (aka: byte[]) type, the ToString method is implemented ultimately by the System.Object base class. The code for that method (via ILSpy) is:

```
public virtual string ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

This reads the type information and calls ToString on the type object itself, which simply returns the name of the type.

As others have answered, in order to get a listing of the items within the array, you need to invoke an enumerator of some sort. There are many different ways in C#, the best option depends on your end goal.

Answer (score 1):

you miss iteration

```
       for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bytes[i]);
        }
```